# How to join a client to two different coherence cluster which are using unicast?

Tags: caching, memcached, communication, multicast, oracle-coherence

I have web application which is using Oracle Coherence 3.7 as a cache provider. 
Below is our requirements:
Have 2 caches, 1 master and 2 Replicated running in UNICAST i.e. using WKA

1. Client at startup will join to master cluster.
2. If there is something wrong in above master cache, client will made to join to replicated cache (by running url or script) without any downtime or startup.
3. All components i.e. the clusters, clients are running on different servers.

I came across this [link](http://codefhtagn.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/joining-multiple-coherence-clusters.html?showComment=1436436582977#c2831382705692744201) where the joining of 2 different cluster shown using multicast; i needed same in unicast.

Please suggest the way. When i try to dynamically switch the client to use replicated cluster i get below error:

> This member could not join the cluster because of a configuration mismatch between this member and the 
>   configuration being used by the rest of the cluster. This member specified a cluster name of "replicated_cache" 
>   which did not match the name of the running cluster. This indicates that there are multiple clusters on this network 
>   attempting to use overlapping network configurations. Rejected by Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2015-07-03 20:08:02.488, 
>   Address=x.x.x.x:8088, MachineId=x, Location=site:x,rack:xxx,machine:xxx,process:master_node_001,member:master_node_001, Role=Cache Server).

Please suggest the approach. Is it possible to join other cluster without downtime or restarting of client or cluster using unicast? **Same is happening in cluster which uses Multicast.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by deploying replicated cluster nodes on weblogic server. When i hit url the, weblogic nodes search replicated cluster locally only. Same is mentioned in Oracle documentation about Replication(read only) cluster. Thanks Abhinav for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

In order or help you I need the following data points:

1. Are you connecting to two different and independent coherence clusters?(If you are not sure then cut and paste your coherence config you are using).
2. If so, do each of the clusters expose a TCP Extends Proxy server IP Address and port number?
3. If you are not sure of what I am talking about in previous two points then let me know.